# Check if the string does not contain any alphabetic characters in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

Is there a way to find out whether the string does not contain any alphabetic characters?

I am thinking of doing a regular expression match. But struggling to do it.

Basically I want to replace "string which does not contain any alphabetic character" to null.

Hope I am clear with my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: This what I have tried. preg_replace('/^[^a-zA-z]*$/',"",$str). I am wondering whether it will work out. I want to replace string only if doesnot contain any alphabets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str     = '1234';
$replace = "test";

$res     =  preg_replace('/^[^a-zA-Z]*$/',$replace,$str);


var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code...

It may help you...

```
   $myString="abC123";

   if( preg_match('([a-zA-Z])', $myString) ) 
   { 
      echo('The string contains letters.');
   }
   else 
   {
      echo('The string contains no letters.');
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/', $myString))
{
    echo 'Contains at least one character';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing.
So, you want to assign NULL to the string if it has no alphabetical charcter in it, right? 
You can do a basic check and replace it.

```
if (!preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/', $str))
{
   $str=NULL;
}
```

If $str doesnt have any letter, then it will become null in this stage. 
Good luck!

Comment: No. I want to make it null, if it does not have any alphabets. "abc123", "abc", "abc!@#" are valid but "123","@#$" are invalid

Comment: See my code above, I updated, it should work for you.